# Documents needed for Immigration

Tags: visas, paperwork, travel-insurance-claim

So, I'm going to Europe from 26th to the 3rd. The original flight tickets were for 17th to 27th, so I had gotten travel insurance for that period. Will I be needed to take out another travel health insurance for the new dates that I will be going to? What other documents will I be asked at immigration control and that I should be carrying with me?

Comment: You might be able to change the dates on your insurance - only your insurance company will know. If not, you'll need a new policy. Is your visa valid for the new dates (if you need one)? What about your hotel booking? Has your itinerary changed significantly as a result of the date change? If so, you might be questioned at the point of entry, especially if it changes the country you should apply to for a visa)

Comment: Can i buy a new insurance policy if the dates cannot be changed? Yes, the visa is valid for 30 days so I'm good. I have hotel bookings too. Itineary has changed and now I will be going to only Paris and Rome. Before I wanted to go to other countries along with France and Italy too. The port of entry is still France and maximum stay is still in Paris. But I have been told itineary changes all the time so its nothing to worry about.

Comment: I'm sure your insurance company will be very happy to take your money again. Ask them.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to ask your insurance provider if they can change the dates to accommodate your new itinerary.

As far as what documents you may need at the border, I'd say all the documents you submitted to support your visa application should also be readily available should the border control officer ask for them. Most importantly I'd say:

- Insurance doc
- Accommodation
- Return Ticket